# How could one grow in rank in TFX?

Tags: tfx

In [TFX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TFX_(video_game)) flight simulator, there are different "ranks", the simplest way to grow in rank is to do training, but it mentions "another way", which I never found.

How else can you do it?